# Handling objects differently based on dates in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am in the process of building out a timeline for a list of objects. The model is simply laid out as follows:

```
class Note(models.Model):

    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    context = models.TextField()
    timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I plan to use this to create a timeline passing the following through:

```
notes = Note.objects.all()
```

However, to make things a bit cleaner, I would like to put a header for each date and then show all events for that date.

Something as follows in my view:

```
    <ul class="timeline">
        <!-- timeline time label -->
    {% for note in notes %}

        {% if note.timestamp_added is first %}
        <li class="time-label">
            <span class="bg-red">
                {{note.timestamp_added|date:"D m, Y" }}
            </span>
        </li>
        {% endif %}

        <li>

            <i class="fa fa-envelope bg-blue"></i>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{note.timestamp_added}}</span>
                <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#">{{note.added_by}}</a> added note</h3>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    {{note.context}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

    {% endfor %}

    </ul>
```

However, is there an appropriate way to write an if statement here based on first instance of the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag.

```
{% ifchanged %}
<li class="time-label">
    <span class="bg-red">
        {{note.timestamp_added|date:"D m, Y" }}
    </span>
</li>
{% endif %}
```

You may want to order your queryset by date to ensure they are in the correct order:

```
notes = Note.objects.order_by('timestamp_added')
```